# NodeJS: Bull jobs sometimes start, sometimes don't

Tags: node.js, redis, jobs

I've implemented a Redis and a microservice to run in 1h intervals, using cron. Sometimes the jobs start, sometimes don't, and I'm not really sure why this is happening.

I have a `server.js` file that starts my backend rest api, a `queue.js` file that process the `Queue` and a `rates.js` file that adds the jobs to the `Queue`:

server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import BullBoard from "bull-board";
import Queue from "./lib/Queue.js";
import routes from "./routes.js";
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// use morgan if in development
if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "development") app.use(morgan("dev"));

// starts the Bull Dashboard
BullBoard.setQueues(Queue.queues.map(queue => queue.bull));

app.use("/api", routes);
app.use("/admin/queues", BullBoard.UI);

app.listen(3333);
```

queue.js:

```
import Queue from "./lib/Queue.js";

Queue.process();
```

rate.js:

```
import rateJobs from "./jobs/exchangeRates/addToQueue.js";
import Queue from "./lib/Queue.js";

// clean queues
Queue.empty("SetArgentinaRate");
Queue.empty("SetBtcPrice");
Queue.empty("SetBrazilRate");
Queue.empty("SetIndiaRate");
Queue.empty("SetSouthAfricaRate");
Queue.empty("SetVenezuelaRate");

// add job to check rates
Object.keys(rateJobs).forEach(job => job);
```

`lib/Queue.js` imports all jobs to a single object:

```
import Queue from "bull";
import redisConfig from "../config/redis.js";

import * as jobs from "../jobs/index.js";

const queues = Object.values(jobs).map(job => ({
    bull: new Queue(job.key, { redis: redisConfig }),
    name: job.key,
    handle: job.handle,
    options: job.options
}));

export default {
    queues,
    add(name, data) {
        const queue = this.queues.find(queue => queue.name === name);

        return queue.bull.add(data, queue.options);
    },
    empty(name) {
        const queue = this.queues.find(queue => queue.name === name);

        return queue.bull.empty();
    },
    process() {
        return this.queues.forEach(queue => {
            queue.bull.process(queue.handle);
        });
    }
};
```

One of the jobs is, i.e., to set an exchange rate:

```
import Currencies from "../../models/currencies.js";
import rp from "request-promise";

export default {
    key: "SetArgentinaRate",
    options: {
        repeat: { cron: "0 * * * *" },
        backoff: { type: "exponential", delay: 30000 },
        attempts: 10
    },
    async handle() {
        // Promise all to get btc price in dest country, spread and btc price
        const [btcArs, { spread }, btc] = await Promise.all([
            rp.get({
                uri:
                    "https://localbitcoins.com/bitcoinaverage/ticker-all-currencies/",
                json: true
            }),
            Currencies.findOne({ currency: "ARS" }).select("spread"),
            Currencies.findOne({ currency: "BTC" }).select("exchange_rate")
        ]);

        // calculate exchange rate
        const exchange_rate = (
            (btcArs.ARS.avg_1h / btc.exchange_rate) *
            (1 - spread)
        ).toFixed(2);

        // set exchange rate to database
        await Currencies.findOneAndUpdate(
            { currency: "ARS" },
            {
                exchange_rate,
                lastUpdate: Date.now(),
                $push: {
                    history: {
                        date: Date.now(),
                        rate: exchange_rate
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Here is a `codesandbox` example: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-kapitsa-x5vyz It's not fully functional because there is no redis instance running, but it's the same as I'm implementing.

When the jobs run, they execute with no errors.

I use `npm-run-all` to start the 3 microservices in parallel:

```
"prod:server": "node --require dotenv/config src/server.js",
"prod:queue": "node --require dotenv/config src/queue.js",
"prod:rates": "node --require dotenv/config src/rates.js",
"start": "npm-run-all -p prod:*",
```

On localhost, sometimes the jobs start, sometimes don't. On production they never start. I can't see why.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!